# Searching for words on a web site using curl with a windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I'd like to use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) to search some patterns on a web site using a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

If the search is successful, it would be great if `curl` could somehow give back a positive sign, (e.g. a `1` in case of success, and a `0` in case of no hits).

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Comment: Does curl not already provide an indication via an error code? Which switches/options did you implement in your curl command? What is currently being returned? What have you tried in capturing and processing it? and What exactly do you need us to help you with? Please note that this site doesn't write code for you, it helps you to fix a specific issue with your own code, which was written to perform the task you required of it, but which exhibits an issue in dong so. Your question is therefore currently off topic, as it is lacking in detail, too broad and doesn't include your problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL to download web content and redirect its output to input of findstr which search trhough downloaded content for pattern occurance.

```
curl.exe %url% | findstr "%pattern%" >NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (echo Pattern found!) else (echo Pattern not found)
```

findstr have limit 8k chars for lenght of piped input. If some lines of your data exceed such limit, than avoid pipeline, save downloaded data into a file:

```
curl.exe -o %filename% %url%
findstr "%pattern%" %filename% >NUL 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (echo Pattern found!) else (echo Pattern not found)
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for your reply!

It shows „Pattern found!“, but also the following: „FINDSTR: Line 106 is too long.“
What does that mean?

Kind Regards,
X3nion

Comment: I have edited my aswer accordingly. Please, mark it as an valid answer if help

Comment: When using the script, it says, that no URL was specified. @echo off

curl.exe -o %Google% www.google.de 
findstr "Example" %Google% >NUL 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 (echo Pattern found!) else (echo Pattern not found)

Comment: Do you have defined %filename% variable prior?

Comment: Ahh do you mean that I have to define a variable before the command? So set filename = Google for example?